# False reporting on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, grep, wget

**Context**

I have a script that pulls down data from a web server using `wget`, checks the filesize of the index.html page using `ls -la`, if it is a certain size using `grep -o`, it is assumed the page is non-functional to customer requirements.

**Code**

```
BADSERVER=()
FILE=SERVER
echo '' > $FILE.txt
<pull a list of hosts down>

if ! ssh -n -f $device -i <sshkey> "yes | rm index.* ; wget localhost:8080 ; ls -la index.html | grep -o 12282" > /tmp/$FILE 2> /dev/null; then
 echo "Unable to connect to $device"
 BADSERVER+=($device)
 echo '' > /tmp/$FILE
elif cat /tmp/$FILE | grep '12282' ; then
 echo 'Page is non functional to customer requirements on $device'
 BADSERVER+=($device)
 echo '' > /tmp/$device
else
 echo 'all is fine on $ip'
 echo '' > /tmp/$FILE
fi
done
```

**Problem**

The script reports that some webservers have the filesize, when manually connecting I can see that the file is not the same size.

**Script traceback**

```
+ ssh -n -f webserver.1014 -i <omitted> 'yes | rm index.* ; wget localhost:8080 ; ls -la index.html | grep -o 12282'
+ grep 12282
+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt
+ echo 'All OK on webserver.1014'
+ echo ''
+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt

+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt

+ ssh -n -f webserver.1015 -i <omitted> 'yes | rm index.* ; wget localhost:8080 ; ls -la index.html | grep -o 12282'
+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt
+ grep 12282
12282
+ echo 'Page is non functional to customer requirements on $device'
Page is non functional to customer requirements on webserver.1015
+ BADSERVER+=($device)
+ echo ''
+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt

+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt

+ ssh -n -f webserver.1016 -i <omitted> 'yes | rm index.* ; wget localhost:8080 ; ls -la index.html | grep -o 12282'
+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt
+ grep 12282
+ echo 'All OK on webserver.1017'
+ echo ''
+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt

+ cat /tmp/SERVER.txt
```

**Actual content of webserver.1015**

```
-r--r--r--.  1 --- --- 25799 Mar 30 23:38 index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server up & running at webserver.1015 ?

Why are you using `;` instead of `&&` ?

- If previous command failed with `;` the second one will run.
- But with `&&` the second one will not run.

[Don't parse the output of ls command.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Extracting only file size with `wget`

`wget http://localhost:8080/index.html --spider --server-response -O - 2>&1 | sed -ne '/Content-Length/{s/.*: //;p}'`

Or with `curl`

`size=$(curl -sI "http://localhost:8080/index.html" | awk '/Content-Length/{gsub("\\r", ""); print $2}')`

Comment: Yes the webserver is up and running, if it could not connect to the server it would inform me. I'll use the recommended wget command and see how the accuracy fairs.

Comment: also use `&&` instead of `;` to assert the previous has completed

Comment: It looks to have increased the accuracy, I had to remove the `index.html` bit as it is generated when pulling the information down, I'll verify that it has increase reliability in the morning as the webservers have a powercycle and maintenance window, if so, I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer

Comment: Of course, you knew it would work, you didn't even have to ask ;) but thanks for the reminder, been a busy day

Comment: glad 2 help m8 ;)